# Why is my Office add-in manifest.xml file with minimum requirement WordApi 1.3 including Office 2016?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I have an Office add-in manifest file with the following requirement set:

```
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
      <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.3"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
```

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability) page indicates that Office 2016 only supports up to WordApi 1.1. However, the manifest validator returns the following satisfied requirements:

```
  - Word for iPad
  - Word 2016 for Mac
  - Word Online
  - Word 2016 or later
```

I'm not understanding why Word 2016 is part of the allowed versions. From what I can tell, 2019 is when WordApi 1.3 was introduced.

The reason for this question is that this add-in won't run on Word 2016 as the API is insufficient, so I need to make it abundantly clear that it should be excluded from testing after submission.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm trying to track down some information for you internally in Microsoft.

Comment: Great, appreciate any help you can give me Rick 

Comment: I have Office 2016 version 2011  Build 13426. Builds 16.0.13426.XXXXX is actually a Monthly Subscription build. At the time of this writing is actually the latest publicly available Office version in Production. Hence  Word JS API > 1.1  will be supported in Office 2016